Spring Cloud Gateway gives error while reading response from GRPC requests "ResponseFacade cannot be cast to class HttpServerResponse"
I have configured the api gateway with grpc. The requests route correctly to the grpc url, however gateway is unable to read the response and it fails with below error.
"ResponseFacade cannot be cast to class HttpServerResponse"
I am using springboot version 3.2.3. The spring cloud version is 2023.0.0. I have added the below dependencies
`implementation (group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
   implementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security')
   implementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web')
   implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'
   implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-openfeign-core'`

Is there anything missed out?
`<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade cannot be cast to class reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse (org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade and reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader @378fd1ac)
--
  | at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.GRPCResponseHeadersFilter.filter(GRPCResponseHeadersFilter.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
  | Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
  | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
  | *__checkpoint ? org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  | *__checkpoint ? HTTP POST "/grpc-api/com.ds.test.adapter.grpc.generated.GraphDataService/fetchGraphIndex" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
  | Original Stack Trace:
  | at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.GRPCResponseHeadersFilter.filter(GRPCResponseHeadersFilter.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
  | at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.HttpHeadersFilter.filter(HttpHeadersFilter.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
  | at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter.lambda$filter$4(NettyRoutingFilter.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
  | at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.lambda$responseConnection$4(HttpClientFinalizer.java:102) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.16.jar!/:1.1.16]
  | at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:163) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar!/:3.6.3]
  | at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar!/:3.6.3]
  | at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar!/:3.6.3]
  | at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:176) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar!/:3.6.3]

<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
`

The api gateway config is as below
``...
..
..
server:
  port: 8080
  http2:
    enabled: true
spring:
  application:
    name: API Gateway
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
    web-environment: false
    web-application-type: reactive
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    allow-circular-references: true
  cloud:
      gateway:
          filter:
            remove-hop-by-hop:
              headers:
                - connection
                - keep-alive
                - transfer-encoding
                - proxy-authenticate
                - proxy-authorization
                - x-application-context
                - upgrade
          httpclient:
            wiretrap: true
            ssl:
              use-insecure-trust-manager: true
          httpserver:
            wiretrap: true
          routes:
            - id: grpc-test
              uri: ${service_grpc_url:grpc://grpc-test:50053}
              predicates:
              - Path= /grpc-api/**
              filters:
              - RewritePath=/grpc-api(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
       ..
..
..`
`

